# Group data with SQL, Lamda or LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I would like to ask is it possible to get data from the database with SQL or update List with Lambda or Linq.

**Data in the Database or in List**

```
  CompanyName         MainName       ChildName
  --------------------------------------------------
  Company1              ABC           
  Company2                             ABC
  Company3              XWY           
  Company4              TTT           
  Company5                             XWY           
  Company6                             ABC
  Company7                             TTT
  Company8                             TTT
```

**What i need**

```
  CompanyName         MainName       ChildName
  --------------------------------------------------
  Company1              ABC           
  Company2                             ABC
  Company6                             ABC  
  Company4              TTT           
  Company7                             TTT
  Company8                             TTT
  Company3              XYZ            
  Company5                             XYZ
```

I can do this by with loop but just wanted to know has anyone knows do it without any loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need conditional `order by` :

```
order by (case when MainName is null then ChildName else MainName end), ChildName;
```

Comment: Thank you.  It is working... Just the CompanyName at the end I put ChildName to get correct list.

Comment: order by $"{MainName}{ChildName}".trim() should give the same result

Answer (score 1):

In C# you could write altrantively to given answer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
  companies = companies
    .OrderBy(c => c.MainName == null ? c.ChildName : c.MainName)
    .ToList();
}

class Company
{
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  public string MainName { get; set; }
  public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```